# Grabbing text from picture

Tags: html, image, software-design

I am looking for a software or for a place to learn about the software that places like TurboTax and many bank deposit places are using today. I would like to implement this into my iOS app and web site.

Trying to be able to take a picture from smartphone or upload image on computer and pull certain information from it or automate the process.

Is there a software for this, or do they create there own? If I would like to make  my own, does anyone know what this is called so I can do more thorough research into this.

Comment: OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision) is one of the software that uses this. It is free and open source. But your question may be flagged as it is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1):

The specific 'term' that you're looking for is `OCR` (Optical Character Recognition). If you simply want a site where you can upload an image to be extracted for free, I recommend [Free-OCR](http://www.free-ocr.com/). If you're looking to make your own program that can extract characters, I'd strongly recommend for looking into incorporating the free [Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) library. It's written in a combo of `C` and `C++`, but you can find wrappers for almost any language.

Again, these are both personal preferences, and any service that offers something similar is likely equally as valid. There is no one 'true' solution to this question, though hopefully the term 'OCR' should give you a good starting point to do your own research ;)

Hope this helps!